# Iterate a tensor in a for loop?

Tags: python, keras, tensor

How do i iterate a tensor in a for loop?..

I want to do convolution on each row of my input_tensor... but can't seem to iterate in a tensor.

Currently trying to it like this:

```
def row_convolution(input):
    filter_size = 8
    print input.dtype
    print input.get_shape()
    for units in xrange(splits):
        extract = input[units:units+filter_size,:,:]
        for row_of_extract in extract:
            for unit in row_of_extract:
                temp_list.append((Conv1D(filters = 1, kernel_size = 1, activation='relu' , name = 'conv')(unit)))
            print len(temp_list)
            sum_temp_list.append(sum(temp_list))
        sum_sum_temp_list.append(sum(sum_temp_list))
    conv_feature_map.append(sum_sum_temp_list)
    return np.array(conv_feature_map)
```

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you're trying to define tensorflow operations for each input. This is a common misunderstanding about the framework.

You must first define the operations that you will perform, all operations must be defined up front. Usually it looks something like this:

```
g = tf.Graph()
with g.as_default():
   # define some placeholders to accept your input
   X = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, shape=[1000,1])
   y = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, shape=[1])
   # add more operations...
   Conv1D(...)  # add your convolution operations
   # add the rest of your operations
   optimizer = tf.train.AdamOptimizer(0.00001).minimize(loss)
```

Now the graph has been defined, all of it. Consider that fixed, you won't add anything to it again.

Now you'll run data through the fixed graph:

```
with g.as_default(), tf.Session() as sess:
   X_data, y_data = get_my_data()
   # run this in a loop
   result = sess.run([optimizer,loss], feed_dict={X:X_data, y:y_data})
```

Note that your data and labels should be feed in a batch, so the first dimension of your data represents N number of datapoints (N=1 is perfectly acceptable of course). You should preprocess the data so it's in that format. For example, a batch of 10 MNIST digits would be in shape `[10,28,28,1]`. That's:

- 10 data samples
- Images are 28 px height
- Images are 28 px width
- It's a grayscale image, so 1 color channel

Comment: I am building my model in keras, which is on top of tensorflow.  I use a lamdba layer to define a layer in keras to do those operation.. thats what the function I use.. I am not quite sure if what I am doing is even legal in keras or tensorflow frameworks... It has to be applicable in keras.. so i guess i made a mistake in adding tensorflow label.

Comment: I don't want to train it.. I just want data to be passed as they are formatted through the Conv1d and then be outputted.

Comment: Same principle applies, you need to define your graph, then use `sess.run(...)`. If you're just doing inference you won't request the optimize OP, rather you'll request an OP that produces the result you're interested in. Tensorflow will know not to bother with backprop and optimization if you don't request that return value. If you've already trained the model then you'll be loading a checkpoint, so define your model components, load the checkpoint, then don't touch it and feed the model with `sess.run`